# Protecting default settings of custom sculpting brushes

Tags: sculpting

I've downloaded some custom sculpting brushes and saved them in my Sculpting startup file. If I'm working on a project and I reset the brush, it reverts to the factory default settings of whatever brush category it's based on. For example, if I reset an Orb brush that's stored in the Sculpt Draw category, I lose the texture, brush icon and custom settings that were saved with the original file, and it just becomes the default Sculpt Draw brush. If I'm lucky, I can undo it, but I end up losing some recent work. And as far as I can tell, the only way to get the brush back is by appending it from the original file (or starting a new project and appending the collection). Is there any way to prevent this from happening? Or do I just need to make sure no to reset any brushes?